# Importing Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

### Original question

I am new to Python and I am learning matplotlib.  I am following the video tutorial recommended in the official User Manual of matplotlib: 'Plotting with matplotlib' by Mike Muller.  The instructor does not show how he imports matplotlib but proceeds instantly with commands such as plot(x, linear, x, square), where x a sequence he has defined.

I tried to run

```
import matplotlib 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.arange(100)
lines = plot(x, 'linear', 'g:+', x, 'square','r-o')
```

and got the error

```
NameError: name 'plot' is not defined
```

### Updated question after solving the import issue

When I try to replicate the examples shown I get an error. Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.arange(100)
lines = plot(x, 'linear', 'g:+', x, 'square','r-o')

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Since I am simply repeating the commands shown in the tutorial I can not understand what I am doing wrong.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

You need to prefix all plotting calls with `plt.` like

```
lines = plt.plot(x, 'linear', 'g:+', x, 'square','r-o')
```

### Longer answer

In Python functions that are not "builtin", i.e. always present, must be imported from modules.
In this case the line

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

is the same as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and means that you are importing the `pyplot` module of `matplotlib` into your namespace under the shorter name `plt`.
The `pyplot` module is where the `plot(), scatter()`, and other commands live.

If you don't want to write `plt.` before every plot call you could instead do

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
```

which will import all functions (symbols) into the global namespace, and you can now use your original line:

```
lines = plot(x, 'linear', 'g:+', x, 'square','r-o')
```

### Edit: Problem with the `plot()` call

Your call to `plot()` is wrong, and the `ValueError` is telling you so.
You are trying to plot the string `'linear'` (6 elements) against `x` which has 100  elements. Since they don't match, `plot()` tells you so.
My guess: `linear` and `square` should be expressions like

```
linear = x
square = x**2
```

Comment: That is **a different question**, so please revert the old question and add the new one as a follow up to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you Hannes.  I tried: plot(x, 'b:+', x**2, 'r-o') and worked.